# How can I theme the Pidgin conversation window?

Tags: themes, gtk3, pidgin, gtk-2, gtkrc

I have been looking for a way to theme the Pidgin conversation window to match my Ubuntu (12.10) theme.  I have tracked it down to the gtkrc-2.0 (gtkrc-3.0?) file and now know that if a customized file is placed in the .purple directory, the default theme will be overridden.  This would work IF I could find the Pidgin GTK widget names for the conversation window.

My ultimate goal would be to add the theme styles to my current theme (Ambiance-dark) along with the widget name calls so that I would only have to backup a single directory for my theme.

**Question:** Does anyone have the widget names for Pidgin readily available?  I know of 2 that possibly pertain to the conversation window:

*pidgin_conv_entry
 
*pidgin_conv_imhtml

...but I really don't know what these affect.

Please feel free to edit my post to help clarify/simplify.  I am somewhat new to Linux and Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried http://www.webupd8.org/2009/05/pidgin-webkit-plugin-adium-conversation.html

Comment: That looks exactly like what I want... however, it says it's only for 32-bit architecture (my box is 64-bit).  Sooo close...  Thanks for the link!